# How can I get ubuntu working on my old macbook when the graphics drivers don't work?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics, gpu-driver

I installed ubuntu normally but the default (Nouveau) drivers that ship with it don't work with my nvidia GeForce 320M meaning I cannot boot up into a system after installation.

I also tried this tutorial to install it and the proprietary drivers properly but I couldn't boot into the "try ubuntu without installing" because of the nouveau driver problem, I meaned to bypass it with "nomodeset" but it still froze after a minute or two not giving me time to install the OS fully.

I have also originally tried debian as the graphics worked fine out of the box BUT my network card didn't work as it needed a properity driver debian didn't ship with I couldn't get working(It was also softblocked)

I'm really getting to the end of my tether now and I just want something that works.

I'm using a macbook A1342 and I want something debian based that supports xfce

Comment: Please precise the macbook model.

Comment: Your kidding right? "I'm using a macbook A1342" that's the model at the end, A1342

Comment: You can try to ask your question here: https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328 There is some threads already: https://ubuntuforums.org/search.php?searchid=21572245